# How to create TIMESTAMPS for SQL query for it to be sortable by date from PHP?

Tags: php, sql, date, time

How to create TIMESTAMPS for SQL query for it to be sortable by date from PHP?

So I have table created by such SQL script

```
CREATE TABLE  `Keys` (
 `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `KEY` INT NOT NULL ,
 `TIMESTAMP` DATE NOT NULL ,
UNIQUE (
`KEY`
)
)
```

What sript should I write to:

- Add timestamps
- To sort\search thru that timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP` in MySQL will be returned to PHP as strings, in the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

Which means you'll be able to use [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) on them, to get an [UNIX Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is the "standard type" on which PHP works for dates/times.

You'll jsut have to consider that a timestamp is a number of seconds since `1970-01-01`

Note there is a limit on [timestamps][3] *(quoting)* :

> The TIMESTAMP data type has a range of
> '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
> '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

And that limit is generally the same on the PHP side.

Then, to manipulate those timestamps, on the SQL side, you can use a wide range of [Date and Time Functions][4].

And they can be sorted like any other data-type -- you can also use the standard `=`, `>`, `<`, ... operators.

Answer (score 0):

You might also just consider storing you dates as int... then use the date() function in php to display them.